# MomentJS using 'm' to add a month gives unexpected result

Tags: momentjs

I'm using Moment.js and for some (probably basic) reason I'm not getting the result I'm expecting:

```
let date = moment("1995-01-25"); 
date.add(2, 'm');           
console.log(date.month());  // Expected 2, outputs 0
```

Comment: You have to use uppercase `M` for adding months, lowercase `m` stands for minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use uppercase `M` for adding months, lowercase `m` stands for minutes, see [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) docs:

```
Key     | Shorthand
-------------------
months  | M
minutes | m
```

Here a working sample:

```js
let date = moment("1995-01-25"); 
date.add(2, 'm');           
console.log(date.month());
console.log(date.format()); //1995-01-25T00:02:00

let date2 = moment("1995-01-25"); 
date2.add(2, 'M');           
console.log(date2.month());  // 2
console.log(date2.format()); // 1995-03-25T00:00:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```